# store data in pivot table in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pivot, pivot-table

I have two tables User table and project table which are linked with many to many relationship project_user table. I want to store project id and user is in pivot table project user when creating the project but I have got following error 
**array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an integer**

My projectController

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
     request()->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'detail' => 'required',
        'location'=>'required',
        'total_cost'=>'required',
        'users' => 'required'

    ]);  
    $project = new Project;
    $project->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $project->user = $request->input('users');
    $users = $request->has('users') ? $request->get('users') : [];
    $user2= User::find($users); 

    $project->users()->attach($request->input([$project ,$project->user_id]));
return redirect()->route('projects.index')
                    ->with('success','Project created successfully.');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing `Project` model instance on `$request->input()` method which is not write.

To solve your problem just follow this way

```php
$userIds = $request->get('users'); // Example value like: [9, 8, 29]
$project->users()->attach($userIds);
```

That's It!